# Power out on one 15amp but has continuity

Tags: electrical

Had the power go out on one 15amp breakers entire circuit, so checked the following.

1. Looked for GFCI and didn't find one for this.
2. Opened the panel and swapped the wire with another one. The wire in question didn't work on another breaker and the breaker that was in question did work with the other line.
3. Unplugged the wire from the breaker and bus bar and started to trace the wire with a wire tracer where it beeps when its the correct wire. It wasn't as loud at the outlets and I dont know if that's normal so then...
4. Used the continuity checker on the unit at the closest wall outlet and one wire after everything was disconnected showed continuity. ( I think this would be the case if it was the first wire in the run or if its still connected to it by way of other wires at its other end.)

I was wondering if a Tripped GFCI would show continuity and if there is a better way to go about it?

It's in a modular home so there may be a box under the house with quick connects from when they put both parts of the house together, but I don't remember seeing one last time I had to go under it. There is also a light with a motion detector on it if those can mess things up in some way that I don't know of?

UPDATE: What I've done and next plans for Troubleshooting (anything wrong or have advise?):

1. I temporarily put the black wire in question with its neutral disconnected on another breaker with its black wire and its neutral still connected. Also, with both neutrals connected.
   Result: (Nothing changed. Does this just tell me if it's a bad breaker or is this a test to see if the neutral is broke? Either way it didn't work.)
2. Bypass the motion sensor on the outside light.
   Result: (Was an end run. Did nothing.)
3. Look for loose wires at the lights with the pull strings first and move on to everything else, leaving everything disconnected from each other to isolate everything and look for the original run wire.
   Result: (I will probably skip this and go to the next step because I dont see this working for any but the starting branch and these strange receptacles break easy.)
4. Get under the house and see if I can find any quick connects from when they put the modular together.
5. Replace the wire if I dont find anything else to fix it.

I posted here after the continuity check passed on one of two isolated wires for the nearest outlet. The wire at the panel was free from the breaker and bus bar with the leads from the tester on it. Does all this sound right? Thanks again.

Comment: What did the breaker service?  What is your original problem, an outlet that doesn't work, a light that won't go on?   Give us details as to what exactly is happening.  The issue may be with the neutral and not the hot wires at all.   More details and facts.

Comment: Everything is out on that circuit. It has a bedroom with three lights where 2 of them are pull strings and an outside porch light. I'm doing a lot of edits above. Right now I'm guessing I need to just get under the house and look for that junction box. Not fun.

Comment: Without any input I'm just doing what seems ok. I guess someone would chime in if there was something better.